# Cannot Load Chrome Extension Javascript File

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I have built a simple app to modify words a user inputs into a text area when working with Adwords. However the javascript file is saying there is an error loading it when I attempt to load my unpacked extension.

[image: chrome extension javascript file loading error]

Here is my manifest:

```js
{
  "name": "Keyword Modifier",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Just copy/paste your keywords and modify them in bulk.",

  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png",
    "default_title": "Keyword Modifier",
    "default_popup": "src/browser_action/browser_action.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.google.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "js/popup.js"
 
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and here is the javascript:

```js
var keywordBox = document.getElementById('keywordBox');
var phraseButton = document.getElementById('phraseButton');
var exactButton = document.getElementById('exactButton');
var modifiedButton = document.getElementById('modifiedButton');

phraseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
     keywordBox.value = ('"' + keywordBox.value + '"'); 
     keywordBox.value = keywordBox.value.replace(/\n/g, '"\n"');
  });
  
exactButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
     keywordBox.value = ('[' + keywordBox.value + ']'); 
     keywordBox.value = keywordBox.value.replace(/\n/g, ']\n[');
  });
  
modifiedButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
     keywordBox.value = keywordBox.value.replace(/^/gm, "+")
     keywordBox.value = keywordBox.value.replace(/ /g, ' +')
  });
```

I've tested this on Glitch and know my program works correctly so Im curious as to what could be causing the error. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is the path to the file correct? Is there a `js` directory in folder that you are attempting to load as an extension?

Comment: Note, all extension files and directories should be within directory containing manifest.json

Comment: yes I've got all my files located within a folder called 'ext1 - test' . Manifest/HTML/JS are all located within sub-directories from there. The javascript file's location is ext1 - test//js/popup.js .

Answer (score 0):

checkout your project:

`"default_popup": "src/browser_action/browser_action.html"`

> > root/src/browser_action/browser_action.html

`"js": [
        "js/popup.js"
      ]`

> > root/js/popup.js

`browser_action.html` html-code `<script src="../../js/popup.js"></script>`